# Problem with scrolling list that overlaps div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a simple list in CSS to display some events and if you hover on an event it should show the details of that event. Due to the length of the list, I've created a simple scrolling bar, but with the scrolling bar when you hover on an event, the div  with hides under the rest of the page. If I don't use the scroll bar this problem doesn't occur.
I will upload the screenshot with and without scroll bar.

[image: Screenshot with the scroll bar]

[image: Screenshot without scroll bar]

```js
 function setEventi(month1, day1, year1) {
  var monthnum = getMonthFromString(month1)

  var datascelta = complete(day1) + "-" + complete(monthnum) + "-" + year1
  var today = new Date();

  readTextFile("./data.json", function(text) {
    var evento = [{
        "classe": [
          "NULL|",
          "1EcB|",
          "1EcC|"
        ],
        "nomeEvento": "uikl",
        "argomento": "jkl",
        "ora_inizio": "08:08",
        "ora_fine": "08:08",
        "dataI": "04-04-2022",
        "dataF": "04-04-2022"
      },
      {
        "classe": [
          "1EcA|",
          "1EcB|",
          "1EcC|",
          "1TB|"
        ],
        "nomeEvento": "Epic Fight from Jotaro Kujo and Dio Brando",
        "argomento": "MUDA MUDA MUDA MUDA MUDA MUDA MUDA MUDA MUDA MUDA MUDA MUDA MUDA MUDA MUDA",
        "ora_inizio": "07:11",
        "ora_fine": "08:15",
        "dataI": "05-04-2022",
        "dataF": "06-04-2022"
      },
      {
        "classe": [
          "NULL|",
          "1EcB|",
          "1EcC|"
        ],
        "nomeEvento": "uikl",
        "argomento": "jkl",
        "ora_inizio": "08:08",
        "ora_fine": "08:08",
        "dataI": "04-04-2022",
        "dataF": "04-04-2022"
      },
      {
        "classe": [
          "1EcA|",
          "1EcB|",
          "1EcC|",
          "1TB|"
        ],
        "nomeEvento": "Epic Fight from Jotaro Kujo and Dio Brando",
        "argomento": "MUDA MUDA MUDA MUDA MUDA MUDA MUDA MUDA MUDA MUDA MUDA MUDA MUDA MUDA MUDA",
        "ora_inizio": "08:11",
        "ora_fine": "08:15",
        "dataI": "05-04-2022",
        "dataF": "06-04-2022"
      }
    ];
    var arr = []
    for (i = 0; i < evento.length; i++) {
      if (datascelta >= evento[i].dataI && datascelta <= evento[i].dataF) {
        var aTmp = null
        var giorno = today.getUTCDate();
        var GiornoFine = evento[i].dataF;
        var GiornoDefinitivo = GiornoFine[0] + GiornoFine[1];
        if (giorno < GiornoDefinitivo) {
          const list = document.getElementById("oggetto_da_modificare");
          if (evento[i].classe[0] === "NULL|") {
            arr.push('0')
            console.log("SIUM")
          } else {
            if (aTmp == null) {
              for (j = i; j < evento.length; j++) {
                aTmp = evento[j].ora_inizio.split(":");
                var nStartMin = (Number(aTmp[0]) * 60) + Number(aTmp[1]);

                arr.push(nStartMin)
              }
            }
            list.innerHTML += "<li class='ciaone' id=" + arr[i] + ">" + evento[i].nomeEvento + " | " + removeBarra(evento[i].classe) + "<div class='saas'> <br>" + "<strong>Inizio </strong>" + evento[i].dataI + " " + evento[i].ora_inizio + "<br><br>" + "<strong>Fine </strong>" + evento[i].dataF + " " + evento[i].ora_fine + "<br><br> <strong>Argomento </strong> <br>" + evento[i].argomento + "</div></li> ";
          }
        }
      }
    }
    sort();
  });

}
```

```css
.box ul {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}

.box ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

ul {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
  padding-inline-start: 40px;
  width: 87%;
  z-index: 0;
  max-height: 215px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.box li {
  margin-left: -28px;
  text-align: center;
}

.box ul:hover li {
  opacity: 0.2
}

.box ul li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 100;
  background: #c617c9;
  box-shadow: 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  color: #fff;
}

.saas {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #076ce4;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 281px;
  margin-top: -10.4%;
  /*margin-left: -3.6%;*/
  margin-left: -103.6%;
}

.ciaone:hover .saas {
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  opacity: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I'm trying to add the json file so it should works properly.

Comment: @Clover "Minimal"

Comment: I uploaded all the files because so maybe is more simple to find the solution

Comment: Removing all the unnecessary code does not only make answering the question easier, it also helps you identify the root cause of your issue. A minimal example of your issue most likely consists of a few lines HTML and CSS. Until you have put in the work to remove the irrelevant code, don't expect others to invest their time to help you.

Comment: Ok, I've edited the post and I left the js function that generates the list and the css for the list that also creates the scroll bar. @thabs

Comment: Very similar situation: https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/

Comment: @CBroe, I've already checked that link but It dind't worked for me, idk why.

Comment: I don't see in your code what is relative to the scrollbar... also, you probably didn't attached the scroolbar correctly to your div and there could  be a conflict between the style of the scrollbar and the style of the div. May be see https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp